# Most efficient way to search a computer

Tags: search, windows-search, search-indexing

Just a while ago, I was doing a search of my whole computer which took days. When I started indexing files using the inbuilt software,my write speed drop a lot.

Is there any way to index files whenever I need to, and not take two cores of CPU out of my use?

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You should only experience a performance decrease during the intial indexing there are built-in protections to prevent this from actually effecting you to much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're searching by filename, I highly recommend "[Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)". It searches the file listing of your NTFS drives, is super-fast, and consumes almost no resources. I now use this *even when I know where the file is* because it's faster than navigating the folder system.

(Update: I forgot to say - install the beta. It's stable and has more features.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to control when indexing will occur but Windows is usually quite clever about not overloading your system while you're using it. Once the initial index is finished the overhead should be minimal.

There are other search products that do allow you to specify when an index is built but I can't think of any that are free. If you're only searching by file name then look for an NTFS-MFT based search tool (like [NTFS-Search](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntfs-search/)) which can search file names in seconds.